# Lumen inconsistent behaviour with GET request

Tags: lumen

For an API I am writing, in my routes file I have:

```
$app->get('item/{id}', 'ApiController@item');
$app->get('groupitems/{group}', 'ApiController@groupItems');
```

In my Controller I have the relevant two functions:

```
public function item($id, Request $request)
{
    if ($this->isAuthorised($request->input('tenant_id'), $request->input('api_code'))) {
        $item = Line::find($id);
        if ($item) { ...

public function groupItems($id, Request $request)
{
    if ($this->isAuthorised($request->input('tenant_id'), $request->input('api_code'))) {
        $items = Line::where('tenant_id', $request->input('tenant_id'))->where('publish', true) ...
```

The calls are both made in exactly the same way, for example:

```
http://api.artlook.com/groupitems/29?tenant_id=2&api_code=o9rty43
```

Please don't try that as the URL is only on a local server at the moment.

My first function runs perfectly. The second one returns an error exception

```
Argument 2 passed to groupItems() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given
```

But they are identical and in the same controller. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here, is that you have declared the parameter name as `{group}`. Therefore, you need to set the argument variable to that name:

```php
public function groupItems($group, Request $request)
...
```

Comment: Thanks - absolutely right. Strangely though I had been using same code in Laravel where it had worked perfectly. Only on Lumen did it fail. Anyway, your correction has completely sorted it, thanks.

Comment: I should think that Laravel uses the same behaviour. However, the two frameworks do use different routing packages. I think Laravel's one is based off of Symfony's components, whereas Lumen uses FastRoute. Truthfully, however, I've never actually tried different variable names in Laravel - not since v3.

Comment: i'm getting the same error with a method that only takes Request $request as a parameter, any ideas ?